# php include_once not working in cacti on archlinux box

Tags: php, include, archlinux, cacti

I had [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) installed on my [ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) box but I don't know after upgrading my system php `include_once()` has stopped working and it doesn't include files any more.

However if I replace `include_once()` with `include()` things start working again, but some files get included twice which causes some other issues.

I don't know how this problem can be fixed, I've almost tried everything but can't get it to work, can someone help me fixing this problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a error or something, because include and include_once do the same work, one repeats one doesn't.
So first try to use include_once to include a php file in a new file (check the permissions given to files). If there is any error, post it here.
If still you're having this problem, put the content of file you want to include it using include_once here and the file that includes that file.
(P.S.: If nothing helped, consider reviewing the php configuration files, or re-installing the PHP)